# How do I remove a URL from the indexes where pip searches for packages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

I am working on a Windows system.
Python version 3.7,
pip version 20.3.3

There was a URL being used in my org for certain packages but now it is inactive.
But every time I try to pip install a new package now, apart from pypi.com, it also searches in the old inactive url.

*Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, **http://org_dev:xxxx@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/simple***

How do I get rid of it so that pip no longer searches there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out finally - the location is %APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini
Found it on the link below, under the heading **Configuration** - **Config file**
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file

Comment: What's the macOS equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Quote from [docs](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/configuration.html)

> The names and locations of the configuration files vary slightly across platforms.
>
> On Unix and Mac OS X the configuration file is: $HOME/.pip/pip.conf
>
> On Windows, the configuration file is: %HOME%\pip\pip.ini

Comment: The link says 'Sorry. This page does not exist yet." Where can I find the file?